# How to make 'Workbook_WindowActivate' be called when I'm using dual display?

Tags: excel, vba

This trigger(and Workbook_WindowDectivate) can successfully be called when I switch window from a workbook to another workbook IN THE SAME SCREEN, but when I switch to a workbook in another screen, it doesn't work. 
It seems they belong to 2 different processes, I can find there are 2 Excel.exe in task manager.

I have a lot of datas and a lot of slicers in one of my workbook which make my sheets run very slowly, but I need keep the global setting 'AutoCalculate' on.
So I'm trying to use a macro to desable it's calculation.
I frequently open multiple windows in 2 screens when working, so my intent is to make this macro can be called when I focus on a workbook in another screen.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there *are* two distinct processes, you can't.

It's two distinct instances of `Excel.Application`, each with their own `Workbooks` collection: you could call one instance "Vegas", and say *"what happens in Vegas, stays in Vegas"*.

Unless... unless your code completely *owns* that other instance:

```
Private WithEvents OtherExcel As Excel.Application

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set OtherExcel = New Excel.Application
    OtherExcel.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub OtherExcel_WindowActivate(Wb As Workbook, Wn As Window)

End Sub

Private Sub OtherExcel_WindowDeactivate(Wb As Workbook, Wn As Window)

End Sub
```

...with a number of caveats:

- It opens a new Excel instance every time
- It won't handle a 3rd instance
- If the execution context dies, the `OtherExcel` object is gone

  - Execution context dies whenever the VBE decides a code change requires recompiling
  - Or whenever an unhandled error occurs
  - Or when an `End` statement is encountered
- If the `OtherExcel` instance is closed the object is gone; if another instance is then started, the `OtherExcel` object is still gone.

You could work around these limitations, by exposing a macro that re-assigns `OtherExcel` on demand. "Attaching" the `OtherExcel` reference to an already-running 2nd instance of Excel could probably be done (`GetObject` comes to mind), but might be unreliable or tricky.